# How to prevent redirect to a certain URL after submission of Contact Form 7 without input required fields

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

My goal is to redirect to an external URL after submission of the Contact Form 7 but only if all required fields are filled in. Instead of this I get a redirect every time, even if all fields are blank.
Fields without input are being marked as invalid but it is not preventing redirection.

`<input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" onclick="window.location.href='https://example.com'" />`

Comment: you can define a function on click to check whether all fields are filled properly. then you may redirect.

Comment: Thank you Ashish. Do you have any idea how to create this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some events which  will help you to achieve your scenario. In your case event should be called once email sent so you can use `wpcf7mailsent` for this.

At the footer add following code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
     window.location.href='https://example.com' 
    }, false );
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you Dipmala. I tried to use DOM event but there is a one feature in my project. I use conditional fields which open certain Submit buttons when certain condition is chosen and each submit button has its own redirect page. I tried to add ID-s to each Submit button to identify them:
`document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    if ( 'submitbutton_id' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        location = 'http://example.com/';
    }
}, false );`
But problem is that event.detail.contactFormId is the ID of the whole contact form, not the current Submit button only.

Comment: Then you can check in this way when you add the condition also some fields are there and its value will be added so add the condition for that field. and add redirection based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Above code is correct. If still redirect happens, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
 window.location.href='#' 
}, true );
</script>
```